# Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

I am implementing Spring Boot application and when it's run from Intellij everythinks works fine, but when the artifact is built and run, gets the next error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.backend.core.CoreApplication.main(CoreApplication.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:591)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

See [here](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/blob/feature/SpringSecurity/out/artifacts/core_jar/log.txt) full log.

I'm using spring-boot-starter-web package which includes Tomcat as a default implementation of a servlet. Seems that exception is thrown because the bean which extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport is created earlier than expected and before the ServletContext is available.

I was trying to change or remove some annotations on WebConfig.java, SecurityConfig.java and CoreApplication.java but always the result is the same.

As a test, if @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class }) is implemented on CoreApplication.java, the exported jar is runned as standalone application without any issue.

So how can I configure WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class in order to run the application waiting for incoming http requests? How can I do in order to build later the bean which extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport and after the ServletContext is available?

Here my repo where there is [pom.xml](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/blob/feature/SpringSecurity/pom.xml), [application.properties](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/blob/feature/SpringSecurity/src/main/resources/application.properties), [config classes](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/tree/feature/SpringSecurity/src/main/java/com/backend/config), [controllers](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/tree/feature/SpringSecurity/src/main/java/com/backend/controller), [main application](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/blob/feature/SpringSecurity/src/main/java/com/backend/core/CoreApplication.java), [models](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/tree/feature/SpringSecurity/src/main/java/com/backend/model) and [repositories](https://github.com/SoftwarDevelop3r/core-backend-api-v1/tree/feature/SpringSecurity/src/main/java/com/backend/repository).

Thanks

Comment: You mean when are you running java -jar command then this error is coming?

Comment: exactly, java -jar core.jar

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem when build jar from Build -> Build Artifacts -> Rebuild. Seems that tomcat is not embeeded with this configuration.

If I build jar from maven menu into Intellij, the exception dissapear.